# how to check if my program is being traced by kdevelop or running in production mode?

Tags: debugging, fork, daemon, trace, kdevelop

Because there is a "fork" invoking in my program, it is difficult to trace my program in KDevelop. It certainly thinks that my program has already finished after the "fork" statement, but the real logic is just now going to start.

Is there a way or codelet which can check whether a program is running in a production/native mode, or being traced in/by KDevelop?

Although the "NDEBUG" macro let us can write a codelet to skip the "fork", I think it is not enough pretty, because sometime we also need let programs with debug-info runs in a native/production mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute arbitrary GDB commands during debugging session in KDevelop. Try breaking on program start and setting `set follow-fork-mode child`. This will make GDB continue with child process after `fork`ing.